# How to feed Gauge with msg.property?

Tags: node-red

In the flow below I have sensor node, which gives temperature in `msg.payload`, which I have successfully connected to temperature gauge. It also gives me humidity in `msg.humidity`, which I would like to be shown on other gauge. How can I connect a property other than `payload` to gauge?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gauge node only uses `msg.payload` to set its value.

Use a `Change` node ahead of the Humidity gauge node to move `msg.humidity` to `msg.payload`.